# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate return Custom Object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I have defined layering in the node.js project.

The structure will be something like below

> user.service.js
>
> user.controller.js

`Service` will be called from `Controller` and inside the `Service`, `mongoose findOneAndUpdate` will be called.

Now, I want to return the Custom object from `Service` after the update but the `result` object is always undefined in `Controller`

**user.service.js**

```
async function activate(tokenParam)
{

  await User.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
     activationToken: tokenParam
   }, 
   {
     $set:{isActive:true}
   }, 
   {
     new: true, 
     useFindAndModify: false
   })
  .exec()
  .then(function (err, doc) {

    var result = new Result();

    if (err)
    {
      result.hasData = false;
      result.exception = err
    }
    else
    {
      result.hasData = true;
      result.data = doc.isActive
    }

    console.log("User Service: Result: " + result)

    return result;
});
}
```

**user.controller.js**

```
userService
.activate(req.params.token)
.then(result => {
  console.log("User Controller: Activate:" + result);

  if (result && result.hasData && result.data) {
    res.status(200).json(result); //Account Activated
  } else {
    res.status(401).json(result); //Account Not Activated
  }
})
.catch(err => next(err));
```

**Expected Output**

```
//console.log("User Service: Result: " + result)
User Service: Result: { ... }

//console.log("User Controller: Activate:" +result)
User Controller: Activate: Result: { ... }
```

**Actual Output**

```
//console.log("User Service: Result: " + result)
User Service: Result: { ... }

//console.log("User Controller: Activate:" +result)
User Controller: Activate: undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your user.service.js like.

```
async function activate(tokenParam)
{
  let result = new Result();
  try {

    const user =  await User.findOneAndUpdate({
                           activationToken: tokenParam
                         }, 
                         {
                           $set:{isActive:true}
                         }, 
                         {
                           new: true, 
                           useFindAndModify: false
                         })
     if(user) {
          result.hasData = true;
          result.data = doc.isActive
          return result;
     }
  } catch(err){
    result.hasData = false;
    result.exception = err;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here result variable holds the `User` object and the object I am using is the `Result` Object

Comment: Ok. I just edited with your wish. I just show that the way last time

Answer (score 1):

```
async function activate(tokenParam)
{
  var result = new Result();

  try{
      var doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
       {
         activationToken: tokenParam
       }, 
       {
         $set:{isActive:true}
       }, 
       {
         new: true, 
         useFindAndModify: false
       })
      result.hasData = true;
      result.data = doc.isActive

   }
   catch(err)
   {
      result.hasData = false;
      result.exception = err
   }

   console.log("User Service: Result: " + result)

   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         resolve(result)
  });
}
```

No reject is there as you are handling the error condition. Also if you want to use reject to see what error you are getting create a new variable inside the function scope and set to err inside catch.

Comment: how will you get `if (err)` there inside `Promise`?!